# How to convert a float into a time format – minutes, seconds and microseconds – in Python?

Tags: python

I’m working with swim results (from an external xls source) in Python and i need to convert a float into a time format – minutes, seconds and microseconds – to perform adding and subtracting operations.
I’m using this function:

```
from datetime import timedelta
def format_result(result):
    seconds = int(result)
    microseconds = int((result * 1000000) % 1000000)
    output = timedelta(0, seconds, microseconds)
    return output
```

When the given input is 131.39, the output should be 0:02:11.390000 but in fact is 0:02:11.389999.
How can I convert this correctly without this precision error?

Comment: Parse it as a string instead of a float

Comment: was thinking the same thing @Falmarri

Comment: float is such a pain in the a** in these situations...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried without converting it into `int`, it works fine, as your expactation it gives 390000  ....!!

```
from datetime import timedelta
def format_result(result):
    seconds = int(result)
    microseconds = (result * 1000000) % 1000000
    output = timedelta(0, seconds, microseconds)
    return output

print format_result(131.39)
```

Comment: Simple and effective. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

All you need to do is convert it to UTC time and `format` datetime

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.strftime(datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(131.39), "%M:%S:%f")
'02:11:390000'
```

What you need to do,

```
import datetime
def format_result(result):
    date = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(result)
    output = datetime.datetime.strftime(date, "%M:%S:%f")
    return output
print format_result(131.39)
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: In my script I have to export the result to xlsx and, as it is, it’s not recognized as time format in Excel (mm:ss,00). In Python it’s OK.